# How to select diferent modals with one function?

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox, w3.js

i tried the lightbox from [W3 school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp) and it works nicely, but if I have more modals on one page the script open all of them together.

Is it possible to set within one script some condition which modal should be opened? Or/and is this the correct way of thinking how to code it?

I omitted from code lower the styling and tons of other content to make it shorter but i didn't do any changes in the original script from W3 except of adding new line of "myModal1" to functions open/closeModal which is the problem i try to solve.

Thank you very much in advance for your answers. :)

```
<div id="epo20-23">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="whole-gallery">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">gallery
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
                <img src="image1.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
                <img src="image2.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            <div class="caption-container">
                <p id="caption"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="column-container">
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="image1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="image2.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="epo24-38">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="whole-gallery">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">gallery
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal1" class="modal">
        <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
                <img src="image3.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
                <img src="image4.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            <div class="caption-container">
                <p id="caption"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="column-container">
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="image3.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)"
                        alt="img3">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="image4.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)"
                        alt="img4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function openModal() {
        document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("myModal1").style.display = "block";
    }

    function closeModal() {
        document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("myModal1").style.display = "none";
    }

    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
        if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
        captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will reply according to your code

You have

```
function openModal() {
        document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("myModal1").style.display = "block";
    }
```

this will open both of the modals together

There are numerous ways to implement this function

A very very basic one : You could add an argument and use an if else-if statement inside the script to specify which one to open

Example :

```
<div id="epo20-23">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="whole-gallery">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;" onclick="openModal("myModal");currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">gallery
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
                <img src="image1.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
                <img src="image2.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            <div class="caption-container">
                <p id="caption"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="column-container">
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="image1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="image2.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="epo24-38">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="whole-gallery">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;" onclick="openModal("myModal1");currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">gallery
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal1" class="modal">
        <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
                <img src="image3.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
                <img src="image4.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            <div class="caption-container">
                <p id="caption"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="column-container">
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="image3.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)"
                        alt="img3">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="image4.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)"
                        alt="img4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function openModal(id) {
        if(id=="myModal")
            document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
        else if(id=="myModal1")
            document.getElementById("myModal1").style.display = "block";
    }

    function closeModal() {
        document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("myModal1").style.display = "none";
    }

    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
        if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
        captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
    }
</script>
```

as you could see the changes:

in the body section:

```
onclick="openModal("myModal");currentSlide(1)" //first h2 div
onclick="openModal("myModal1");currentSlide(1)" //second h2 div
```

script section:

```
function openModal(modal) {
        if(modal=="myModal")
            document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
        else if(modal=="myModal1")
            document.getElementById("myModal1").style.display = "block";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but that fix only part of the problem. When i reached the end of the gallery and clicked on the next button it doesn't drop me back at the first slide but continue with the first slide of the gallery number 2.